# GridView Control with private fields when i bind the gridview

Tags: gridview, private, field

```
enter code herepublic List<VivaClass> ReturnVivaObj() //viva class all field is private
{
    List<VivaClass> Objlst = new List<VivaClass>();
    VivaClass obj = null;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection hookup = new SqlConnection(new ConnectionString().GetConString(("SqlConString")));
        string query = "Select ID,GroupID,StudentName,ProjectName,City,Date,Time,isMake FROM SchedualTB";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, hookup);
        hookup.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            obj = new VivaClass();
            obj.SetGet_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDGroupID = Convert.ToString(dr["GroupID"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDStudentName = Convert.ToString(dr["StudentName"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDProjectName = Convert.ToString(dr["ProjectName"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDCity = Convert.ToString(dr["City"]);
            obj.SetGetDate = dr["Date"].ToString();
            obj.SetGetDTime = dr["Time"].ToString();
            obj.SetGetDIsMake = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isMake"].ToString());
            Objlst.Add(obj);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return Objlst;
}
enter code herepublic List<VivaClass> ReturnVivaObj()  // this function return the list of viva objec for binding the Gridview control
{
    List<VivaClass> Objlst = new List<VivaClass>();
    VivaClass obj = null;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection hookup = new SqlConnection(new ConnectionString().GetConString(("SqlConString")));
        string query = "Select ID,GroupID,StudentName,ProjectName,City,Date,Time,isMake FROM SchedualTB";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, hookup);
        hookup.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            obj = new VivaClass();
            obj.SetGet_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDGroupID = Convert.ToString(dr["GroupID"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDStudentName = Convert.ToString(dr["StudentName"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDProjectName = Convert.ToString(dr["ProjectName"]);
            obj.SetGetStudentObJ.SetGetDCity = Convert.ToString(dr["City"]);
            obj.SetGetDate = dr["Date"].ToString();
            obj.SetGetDTime = dr["Time"].ToString();
            obj.SetGetDIsMake = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isMake"].ToString());
            Objlst.Add(obj);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    return Objlst;
}
enter code here<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGroupID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupID") %>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student ID">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStudentName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentName") %>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectName") %>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Status" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgStatus" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Change User status"  ImageUrl="~/Image/logo/statusActive.png"></asp:ImageButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
enter code hereprivate void FillGrid() // Error: 'VivaClass' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'
{
    GridView1.DataSource = new StudentIdentity().ReturnVivaObj();
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

am trying to bind the data, but exception throw that VivaClass does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.I dont have idea about how to bind through the code. Can any once give me any link or solution for this. Thanks